# password protect my website with IIS7

Tags: .net, .htaccess, iis-7, password-protected

i have a website with c# deployed on a windows server 2008 and IIS7

now it is accessible to everyone, but i need to passsword protect it (like with .htaccess)
for now i  only managed to deny any access to it ! via disabling anonymous authentification from ii7

please bear with me,total newbie here
thanks

Comment: Did you google around at all?  It doesn't look like you did.

Comment: for ur information..i did!

Comment: Voted down for snarky response to questions.

Answer (score 1):

windows authentification is what i need,
 so i added it and enabled it,then i get a prompt asking for credentials..the windows session credentials
its fine for me now
thanks

Comment: Make sure you do this over ssl or passwords will come cleartext over the net

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for you to do this is to put a login form on your site.  There are a lot of different variables to take into consideration, but here's a good starting place for figuring out the basics...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240

Comment: this is not the way i want to do it!

Comment: Then how DO you want to do it?

Comment: its only temporary while the website is in devloppement phase. i'd like something that works like .htaccess

Comment: Tried searching? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iis+htaccess

Comment: not all 4444 of them of course

Comment: finally found something in google,works for me for now,thanks :)

Comment: @astrocybernaute: Could you add the way that works for you as a separate answer?